# How to take a variable input and attach it to another variable?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm having difficulty finding an answer to this, primarily because I don't know how to properly phrase the question into a simple google query.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

A user inputs a number and that digit is attached to the end of a variable name (see at the bottom).

```
int enablePin1 =1;
int revPin1 = 2;
 int fwdPin1 =3;
 int enablePin2 = 4;
 int revPin = 5;
 int fwdPin2 = 6;
 int enablePin3 = 7;
 int revPin3 = 8;
 int fwdPin3 = 9;

int ch = Serial.read();

if (isDigit(ch)){
int selection = (ch - '0');

 setMotor (selection, 255, 0);
}

//User inputs a motor number between 1 -3. Below, 255 and 0 are speed & direction
//For example (2 , 255, 0)

//////////////////////HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP...
//////////I want each (motorSelection) variable to be replaced with whatever 
 the user inputs, in this case, with 2, so that it is enablePin2, revPin2, fwdPin2.

 void setMotor1(int motorSelection, int speed, boolean reverse)
{
  analogWrite(enablePin(motorSelection), speed);
  digitalWrite(revPin(motorSelection), ! reverse);
  digitalWrite(fwdPin(motorSelection), reverse);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do exactly what you described.  However, you can achieve your larger goal using arrays instead of the numbered variables:

```
static const int enablePin[3] = { 1, 4, 7 };
static const int revPin[3]    = { 2, 5, 8 };
static const int fwdPin[3]    = { 3, 6, 9 };

// ...
int ch = Serial.read();
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '3') {
    int selection = ch - '0';

    analogWrite(enablePin[selection], speed);
    digitalWrite(revPin[selection],   !reverse);
    digitalWrite(fwdPin[selection],   reverse);
}
```